# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I am facing an issue with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'
```

When I checked the packages installed with pip freeze i could see scikit-learn installed.

What shall I do?

Thanks